# Where can I find a comprehensive guides to linear algebra and calculus?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm a software engineer with a keen interest in all sorts of artificial intelligence and machine learning applications, and also quantum computing.

Both areas require quite a bit of linear algebra and calculus, and I'm afraid mine is quite rusty.

I'm looking for a good source on either or both. I'm not exactly a stranger to them, I'm familiar with the basics (functions, basic matrix operations, and a bit of single variable calculus I can remember from high school), but I'm more of a logic & set theory guy.

Does anybody know of a good source that covers more than the basics, but isn't too technical? (I'm not a dedicated mathematician)

Much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you looking for online sources, or books, or both? How much are you willing to spend? :P

Comment: Online sources if one is available, but googling hasn't turned up much yet, so I'm open to the idea of books too :)

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Linear-Algebra-Fourth-Edition/dp/0980232716/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1346740402&sr=8-4&keywords=linear+algebra (Gilbert Strang's Intro to Linear Algebra) is pretty good; also, he uses code to illustrate ideas (in MATLAB and I think also FORTRAN), which might be up your alley. I'm not incredibly familiar with what calculus is needed for machine learning and quantum computing; do you know what level of calculus you'll be needing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Linear Algebra**

For video lectures, [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/) is Gilbert Strang's video lectures. As a companion textbook, [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong) by Sergei Treil is a great resource despite its name.

For traditional textbooks, I'm sure these questions are good resources:

[What is a good book to study linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/what-is-a-good-book-to-study-linear-algebra)

[More Theoretical and Less Computational Linear Algebra Textbook](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87362/linear-algebra-textbook)

**Calculus**

[Paul's](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx) online math notes may be a good place to start for a free calculus textbook. [Here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/) are MIT's video lectures on single variable calculus.

For traditional textbooks, I'm sure this question will give a panoply of suggestions:

[suggest textbook on calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63504/suggest-textbook-on-calculus)