# Second Linear Algebra Text for Budding Mathematician

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I have already worked through Gilbert Strang's *[Introduction to Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980232716)* and am interested in learning more Linear Algebra.

**What is a good follow-up to Strang for a budding mathematician?**

EDIT: The OP in the linked question is a physicist and is interested in topics that apply more to physicists. I am inquiring about a second Linear Algebra text that would be appropriate **specifically for someone interested in pure mathematics.**

Comment: @ZevChonoles The OP in the linked question is a physicist particularly interested in Hilbert Spaces, etc. My interest is in mathematics.

Comment: Mohino: Take a look at some of the [suggestions here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87362/linear-algebra-textbook?rq=1). Perhaps, e.g., you'd like to explore Hoffman & Kunze, or Axler's text.

Comment: @Mohino In my experience, linear algebra is very useful as a tool, and it's not really something you can "learn more of". The basic classification of vector spaces and the maps between them is standard; anything else seems to me to be esoteric tools for very specific applications. Still, I'm happy to be proved wrong. You might like to consider studying rings and modules (generalisations of fields and vector spaces respectively; somewhat harder, and a large current area of mathematical research). It may help to learn some group theory first.

Comment: That said, I don't know how far Gilbert Strang's course goes. I might be imagining you've gone much further than you have.